# How to automatically upload a file to my FTP every 30 seconds?

Tags: xml, ftp, refresh, filezilla

I have an XML document housed in my computer and I would like to send this document to my FTP automatically. Every 30 seconds (example) it automatically sends the XML document back to FTP (a refresh) because it is updating it. I have tried with FileZilla or WinSCP and so far unsuccessfully.

Is there any way, any software you know that allows you to do this upload automatically?

Thanks for listening!

Comment: Any upload should work.  You just need to add a timer to do it every 30 seconds.